# Big Query Nested and Repeated data

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

may someone give some advice on this? There is 2 repeated fields. I can't run the query.
My query is:

SELECT
t
FROM `claritas-bigdata-poc.Sushi_King.member_with_transaction`,
UNNEST(transactions.transaction) AS t

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTFPd.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7kUd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([official docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#querying_array-type_fields_in_a_struct)):

```
SELECT t 
FROM claritas-bigdata-poc.Sushi_King.member_with_transaction, UNNEST(transactions), UNNEST(transaction) AS t
```

or

```
SELECT transaction 
FROM claritas-bigdata-poc.Sushi_King.member_with_transaction, UNNEST(transactions)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach

```
select t.*
from `claritas-bigdata-poc.Sushi_King.member_with_transaction` t1, 
t1.transactions t2, t2.transaction t
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT transaction.*
from `claritas-bigdata-poc.Sushi_King.member_with_transaction`
,UNNEST(transactions) transactions
,UNNEST(transactions.transaction) transaction
```